# GetLatest Value from AppConfig using terrafrom

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, app-config, aws-app-config

My pipeline use few values with `tf` script and recently I moved all these values to `Aws App Config` But still few places have references within `tf` for monitoring purposes. How can I read this value from app config.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/appconfig_configuration_profiles

Something like this

```
data "aws_appconfig_configuration_profiles" "example" {
  application_id = "some-app-id"
}

data "aws_appconfig_configuration_profile" "example" {
  for_each                 = data.aws_appconfig_configuration_profiles.example.configuration_profile_ids
  configuration_profile_id = each.value
  application_id           = aws_appconfig_application.example.id
}
```

then refer to this app ID at another place

```
resource "aws_appconfig_configuration_profile" "example" {
  name           = "my-configuration-profile"
  application_id = "some-app-id"
  location {
    content_type = "application/json"
    uri          = "app-config-file.json" 
  }
}
```

One another way I can think of is to download file and then read value from local file.

```
aws appconfig  get-configuration --application some-app-id --environment prod  --client-id local-cli  --configuration config-name outfile > output.json
```

```
locals {
    # get json 
    data = jsondecode(file("output.json"))
}
```

Comment: What does "dynamically" mean? Can you provide more details?

Comment: Updated the question. Dynamically reading mean having some json key reference within `tf`

Comment: I don't know any direct way, but there's nothing preventing you from wrapping your AWSCLI command with `shell_script` data source ([docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/scottwinkler/shell/latest/docs/data-sources/shell_script)). Then you'll get a JSON output same as your file, but right during `terraform {plan,apply}` without any external steps.

Comment: I was having the same thought. I just shared the content of shell script.

Comment: I mean that you don't need the intermediary file - just `data.shell_script.your_script.output` in place of `jsondecode(file("output.json"))`